# Guardando valores de um array em uma única variável

Tags: php, array

Eu poderia fazer assim

```
$array = array(12, 14, 121, 123);
$var = $array[0].", ".$array[1].", ".......
echo $var
```

Mas como fazer se eu não souber o tamanho exato do *array*?

Porque eu estou recebendo ela através de um *post* que vem de um `<select multiple="multiple"></select>`

Assim não dá pra saber o tamanho exato do mesmo.

Comment: Já tentou foreach?

Comment: Desculpe-me... Mas como? No modo que eu estou pensando não tem como guardar todos os valores.... Mas sempre o último inserido...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente é isto que quer:

```
$array = array(12, 14, 121, 123);
$var = "";
foreach ($array as $item) $var .= $item . " ";
echo $var;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/S8Wi1o). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zbqknlwe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/StringBuilder.php).

[Manual do `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

[Manual do operador de atribuição composta](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Desta forma você varre todos os elementos. Existem diversas outras formas de obter o mesmo efeito, mas esta é a mais apropriada.

Neste caso específico pode fazer algo mais simples:

```
implode($array, ", ");
```

Comment: Obrigado! Ainda não conhecia operador .= haha. Mas funcionou perfeitamente aqui!

Comment: Esse `implode` fez em uma linha o que meu código fez em quase 10  kkkk vivendo e aprendendo.

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução, formatando do jeito que você sugeriu na pergunta, com virgula:

```
$array = array(12, 14, 121, 123);
$newVar = "";
$arrayLength = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++){
    if($i == ($arrayLength-1)){
        $newVar .= $array[$i];
    }else{
        $newVar .= $array[$i].",";
    }
}
echo $newVar;
```

Comment: Para adicionar as virgulas eu fiz assim, Diego : $var.=", ".$item; E na hora de imprimir, usei o substr() iniciando no 2

Comment: @Naldson como assim? Não entendi.

Comment: http://ideone.com/undskA

Comment: @Naldson muito bacana, assim vc nao precisa mexer com indice do array hehe

Comment: @Naldson esse seu código não faz sentido.

Comment: @bigown Pois é... Depois que eu vim ver que é melhor apenas usar o "implode($array, ", ");"

Answer (score -4):

Faz assim que é mais simples:

```
$array = array(12, 14, 121, 123);

foreach ($array as $item) {


echo "<br>".$item;

}
```