# Exibir apenas valores do array

Tags: php

Eu sou inciante em PHP e estou estudando nesse momento os arrays, e estou com uma duvida boba.

Quando eu imprimo minhas arrays, ela vem dessa forma

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( [0] => 10 )
  [1] => Array ( [0] => 20 )
  [2] => Array ( [0] => 30 )
  [3] => Array ( [0] => 40 )
  [4] => Array ( [0] => 50 )
)
```

Meu interesse é que sejam exibidos apenas os numeros.

```
10, 20, 30, 40 50
```

Codigo php

```
while (($linha = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
{

  $carros[] = $linha;
  //print_r($linha);

}

fclose($file);
print_r($carros);
```

Toda ajuda será bem vinda

Comment: Eu alterei minha pergunta, pois os sites não me ajudaram.

Comment: De onde vem esse array? Sua pergunta ta muito confusa.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, baseando apenas no Array que você mostrou na pergunta, para exibir apenas os valores você pode usar `for` ou `foreach`:

```
$arr = Array (
    0 => Array ( 0 => 10 ),
    1 => Array ( 0 => 20 ),
    2 => Array ( 0 => 30 ),
    3 => Array ( 0 => 40 ),
    4 => Array ( 0 => 50 )
);
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo $value[0]. " ";
}
```

Veja funcionando: http://ideone.com/kvF17H

Peguei a dica do @Maniero [**neste post**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96915/28595).

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função nativa do php

```
array_values($array);
```